# How to display exact decimal value instead of exponential in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I've a data table which is attaching to a DataGrid and in that few columns are having decimal values and we can edit these values in GUI, but when ever i edit a value from 0.01 to 0.000000001 it's displaying 1E+8 something exponential value in DataGrid from GUI.

So any one help me out that how can i display exact value instead of exponential.

Thanks
@Nag

Comment: And i tried by attaching current culture info to the Thread, but it won't gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
columnName.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00#######"
```

Comment: Will this work for any value, i may get values like 0.0138, 0.000001, 123.1 like this... And these are dynamic columns

Comment: It says that the cells should contain decimal values with 2 to 9 decimal places. 123.1 will become 123.10, if you want it to remain 123.1 the format is "0.0########" aka from 1 to 9 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, what i mean to say is what ever value should be there in the data table that should display in DataGrid which is having dynamic columns. I'm getting values to my DataGrid everything fine except values like 0.0000001 it displaying exponential value in DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

//C# code

this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N";

Comment: DataGrid having dynamic columns

Comment: what do u mean by dynamic columns,dnt u know about the column position in the grid?

Comment: It means columns will create at runtime depending on the requirement. Also just attaching data table to the DataGrid so need to do modifications on data table only.